# SNICallback is never called

Tags: node.js

I was trying to point two independent domain to my node.js server. Everything woks well but HTTPS.
I realized my only option for having two separated HTTPS address on a single web server is using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) but I couldn't make it work in my node server.
Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
  passphrase: 'something',
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/xxx.crt'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt'),

  // Dynamic certificate check
  SNICallback: function (servername) {
    console.log('sni:', servername); // This function is never called
  }
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

  req.on('end', function () {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    res.end('{}');
  });

}).listen(443);
```

I know SNI in not supported by all browsers and it only works with TLS, but I tested it with Chrome 36, Firefox 30 and IE 10.
I also tested changing `secureProtocol` to `'TLSv1_method'` and `'SSLv3_method'` but it didn't work too.

Is there anyway to make it work?
Is there any other solution that does not require SNI? It's not related to node but I know there is a [gnutls_certificate_set_retrieve_function2](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/gnutls_certificate_set_retrieve_function2/) function in GNU for that.

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: I'm using nodejs v0.10.29

Comment: Did you resolve problem?

Comment: @socketpair not yet. but I don't know why I wanted it now :) It's for years ago